# How to change bitmap without adding another child to the stage

Tags: actionscript-3, url, random, bitmap, addchild

I know exactly what this function is doing, however I don't know how to change it so that the 3 symbols only ever add once and only the bitmaps change. Thank you for your help! It's probably something simple, but I can't seem to figure it out, I am an intermediate as3 programmer but still have some holes in my knowledge.

```
var randCount:int = 3
        function loadImage():void
        {
            for(var i:int = 0; i<randCount; i++)
            {
                var imgLoader:Loader = new Loader();
                var imgRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
                imgRequest.url = "../img/planet" + int(2*Math.random()) +".png";
                trace(imgRequest.url);
                imgLoader.load(imgRequest);
                imgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedImg);
            }
        }

        function onLoadedImg(e:Event):void
        {
            e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedImg);
            var bmp:Bitmap = e.currentTarget.content;
            bmp.x = 600;
            bmp.y = Math.random() * 520;
            bmp.width = 80;
            bmp.height = 80;
            addChild(bmp);

        }
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeBitmap);
        function changeBitmap(event:MouseEvent):void {
            loadImage();
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to show 3 images every time ?

Comment: yes, I have fixed the above problem, one more question. If i wanted the y value to evenly space out the 3 instances of the image (bmp), how would I go about that? Instead of randomly placed

Comment: I put an answer for your both questions, take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guessing you ask the question that way because you are just adding more bitmap on top of the previous ones and by "change bitmap" you mean adding new ones.

You need to remove the ones you added previously and then you can add new ones. For example a simple change:

```
    var randCount:int = 3
    var bitmaps:Array = [];
    function loadImage():void
    {
        for(var i:int = 0; i<randCount; i++)
        {
            var imgLoader:Loader = new Loader();
            var imgRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
            imgRequest.url = "../img/planet" + int(2*Math.random()) +".png";
            trace(imgRequest.url);
            imgLoader.load(imgRequest);
            imgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedImg);                
        }
    }

    function onLoadedImg(e:Event):void
    {
        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedImg);
        var bmp:Bitmap = e.currentTarget.content;
        bitmaps.push(bmp);
        bmp.x = 600;
        bmp.y = Math.random() * 520;
        bmp.width = 80;
        bmp.height = 80;
        addChild(bmp);
        while(bitmaps.length > randCount)
        {
            var oldbitmap:DisplayObject = bitmaps.shift() as DisplayObject;
            removeChild(oldbitmap);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply! I'm getting an error saying the it cannot convert the array into a display object.

Comment: I copied your code exactly and got two errors. Error: Implicit coercion of a value of type uint to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.  Error: Comparison between a value with static type uint and a possibly unrelated type Array. while (_bitmaps.length_ > bitmaps) var {oldBitmap:DisplayObject = _bitmaps.unshift();_ removeChild(oldBitmap);} (italicized parts are the source of the problem)

Comment: yeah I had a typo, it's untested code. See the edit.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed one error. It's still fussing about bitmaps.unshift();  Error: Implicit coercion of a value of type uint to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Comment: can I still use button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeBitmap);
        function changeBitmap(event:MouseEvent):void {
            loadImage();
        } when I do the swf freezes. Besides that there are no errors

Comment: Thanks for your time BotMaster! Works great!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new BitmapData and assign it to the [Bitmap#bitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Bitmap.html#bitmapData). That is the most economic way to deal with the problem. (One BitmapData for many Bitmaps works as well.)

Comment: he's loading them so his BitmapData are coming wrapped up in a Bitmap already, there's nothing to gain on switching bitmapdata between 2 existing bitmap.

Comment: Swapping the BitmapData is not an option?

Comment: swapping BitmapData would be good if that would save the creation of a Bitmap but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are looking for, you can also use a `Sprite` as a container of your images, and every time you can remove them to add the new ones. Take a look on this example :

```
var nb_images:int = 3,
    bmp:Bitmap,
    // set 5px as vertical margin between images
    img_margin:int = 5, 
    img_request:URLRequest,
    img_loader:Loader;

var images_container:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(images_container);

function remove_all_images(): void 
{
    // remove all images
    for(var i:int = images_container.numChildren - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        images_container.removeChildAt(i);
    }
}

function load_images(): void 
{
    remove_all_images();
    for(var i:int = 0; i < nb_images; i++)
    {
        // to generate randomly values between 0 and n (excluded) we use : int(n * Math.random())
        img_request = new URLRequest('images/' + (int(nb_images * Math.random())) + '.png')
        img_loader = new Loader();            
        img_loader.load(img_request);
        img_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_img_loaded);                
    }
}

function on_img_loaded(e:Event): void 
{
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_img_loaded);
    bmp = e.currentTarget.content;      
    bmp.smoothing = true;
    bmp.x = 0, bmp.width = bmp.height = 80;
    // set image.y
    // 1st image : y = 0, 2nd image : y = 80 + 5 = 85, 3rd image : y = 2 x 85 = 170
    bmp.y = images_container.numChildren * (bmp.height + img_margin);
    // add the image to images_container
    images_container.addChild(bmp);
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot!! Would upvote if I could!